# How to set an auto width to a div that is a background for a button

Tags: css

I am attempting to put a div around the buttons in my app. The divs should have a 5px padding around the button. However, the div keeps spanning the entire width of the page unless i set the width with a number. Obviously it would be much easier to have an 'auto' width for every div instead of specifying width for each individual button. Is there any way to do this?

stylesheet:

```
.button_div {width: auto; height: auto; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;}
```

view:

```
<div class="button_div">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'auto' width for a div *is* for the div to take up the full width. Div's are block-level by default.

To get a div to collapse down to the size of its contents, you need to either float it, or set the display to inline-block.

Comment: @DA, thanks! setting this div to inline-block worked. In that it was just this one element i don't foresee any complications... djou?

Comment: The only complication with inline-block would be iffy support in older versions of IE (but isn't that always a complication? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use

```
<button class="someClass"/>

.someClass {padding: 5px;}
```